# simpleSAML Remote passive login

Tags: php, saml, adfs, simplesamlphp

One of my client asked me to develop an hybrid application for them using ADFS authentication trough a SAML 2 protocol. In order to do that, i did install on my Debian 9 the framework simpleSAMLphp (http://simplesamlphp.org) which is basically a php SAML integration. I correctly created the trust between my Service and their Identity Provider.

So here I am, trying to build an API in php which would basically handle all my sessions whatever platform im using. I've been following closely their documentation, and I'm stuck on a subject which is kinda tricky, and i didn't manage to find a suitable answer for it.

The documentation wants me to use the function requireAuth() to test if my user is authenticated and if not it returns the IdP landing page. All of this is done so i can parse attributes returned by the authentication, which basically would be the token issued by the server.

```
<?php
require_once('/var/simplesamlphp/lib/_autoload.php');
$as = new \SimpleSAML\Auth\Simple('default-sp');

$as->requireAuth();
$attributes = $as->getAttributes();
print_r($attributes);
?>
```

But this behaviour is not really suited for an API like mine. Since i want my sessions to be managed from my API.

What i want to do is the following:

- The user enter his credentials (mail and password) in a custom form
- We send the credentials to my API which send a request and parse its answer
- Show or Hide content based on response

So my question is the following, is this possible ? And if yes, is there a way for me to manage an ADFS authentication in PHP via a POST/GET request, or XML, or something like this ?

Im sincerely grateful for those who will take time to answer my request.

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

well you can set you saml as an SP ann have it make the logi on it's on.

example

```
1: user opens the aplications and choose to login is with saml.
2: he gets the saml sp that is configured with you application. he choose the company he wants to login as then he logs in.
3 if the login is approved you can redirect him back to your application and log him autmatic in.
```

I have used this method before (saml as sp) and it works fine.

Goodluck

Comment: Thank you for your time, and answer.
But can you be a little more specific on how you managed to do it ? Did you use a webview or something like this ? Because i don't really see how you let the user connect through an ADFS landing page on your app, beside managing the connection in a webview and and parsing its return to finally show your final view.

Comment: ok, You need to have a working SAML SP configuration and then make a Vhost with the same alias leading to your API. thn you make a function with a the simple saml authentication steps. and leave the login views and redirects all in the hands of SAML. The only thing you need to make is a button on your API that says SINGLE-SIGN-ON if the klick on it they will be redirct to the SAML SP and then the saml will take care of the login. If the login is ok then you add a login into your api by ferther configring the Saml login function.(just make them log in into your api without user and pas)